# Can't log in to Google account to install Google Authenticator because of 2FA

Tags: google-authenticator

Can't remember what it is called, but I used to have that Google authentication code generator app on my phone which would be used to enter a special code for the 2-step Google authentication system.

My phone has been damaged, so I have a new one now.  But I can't log into Google because I don't have that authentication app installed on my phone, and I can't install that authentication app on my phone because I need the authentication code.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the backup verification codes.  The backup methods are the only way to get back into your account if you have damaged your phone.

Answer (score 2):

Goto [security tab of your Google account settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security) and disable 2-step verification.

Then install the [authenticator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en)

Now you can re-enable 2 step verification which should work normally.

Comment: To get to that page I need to log into my google account.  How do I log into my google account without the google authenticator?

Comment: @oshirowanen log in to your account using a computer. Do you *not* remember your username and password for your google account?

Comment: I know the username and password, what I don't know is the code generated by the google authenticator which I normally get from my phone.

Comment: @oshirowanen so you cannot either login to the account using your computer or download the app using the link provided in this answer, yes?

Comment: That is correct.